# Average amount of characters in varchar MS SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently trying to select multiple columns including note_id, notes_date_time, comments, DATALENGTH(comments) as 'note_length', from a table labelled job_notes.

However, I am only aiming to display the above when the length of characters within a comment is greater than the average length of the other comments. (The data type for comments is VARCHAR something).

I am also aiming to order by the length of the comments in descending order.

This is my code:

```
SELECT note_id, notes_date_time, comments, DATALENGTH(comments) AS 'note_length'
FROM job_notes
WHERE DATALENGTH(comments) > AVG(DATALENGTH(comments))
ORDER BY DATALENGTH(comments) DESC;
```

Upon execution, I am met with the following error message

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Go read the documentation about datalength - it does not count characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT note_id, notes_date_time, comments, DATALENGTH(comments) AS 'note_length'
FROM job_notes
WHERE DATALENGTH(comments) > (select AVG(DATALENGTH(comments)) from job_notes)
ORDER BY DATALENGTH(comments) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, you can't use aggregate functions in the `WHERE`, and the `HAVING` won't help you here. Personally, I would suggest using a CTE and a Windowed Aggregate function:

```sql
WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT note_id,
            notes_date_time,
            comments,
            DATALENGTH(comments) AS Note_Length, --Don't use single quotes for aliases, they are meant for literal strings
            AVG(DATALENGTH(comments)) OVER () AS Avg_Note_Length
     FROM dbo.job_notes)
SELECT note_id,
       notes_date_time,
       comments,
       Note_Length --Don't forget to divide by 2 if you want characters and this is an nvarchar
FROM CTE
WHERE Note_Length > Avg_Note_Length;
```